# Facebook Open Graph image keeps getting cropped despite correct proportions

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph, crop

Despite seemingly following all the guidelines for including Open Graph objects in my code, I cannot get Facebook to display my images correctly in the share dialog. These are the meta tags that my website currently provides:

```
<meta property="og:url"content="http://tombakas.com/delfinariumas/5" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Delfinariumas"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Moderni išmintis per patikrintas lūpas"/>
<link rel="image_src" type="image/png href="http://tombakas.com/static/delfinariumas/thumbnails/5.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://tombakas.com/static/delfinariumas/thumbnails/5.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="315" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```

The image is of the 600x315 dimensions, the minimum accepted according to the specification. Regardless, it is still being previewed as a cropped square, instead of showing it at full size. I've scanned the forums and SO to no avail, so I'm really flabbergasted.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The Share dialog always displays a square excerpt of the image in preview, there is nothing you can do about that. (Apart from making the image square in the first place – but that is not advisable, because then it would look different in the actual view of the post.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, CBroe. It lead me to trying to share the examples provided by sites like [ths one](http://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/images-photos-facebook-sizes-dimensions-types) and, indeed it still showed up as a square.    

However, sharing from a different type of page, not personal profile, shows a full sized image at proper proportions. I wish it was available for personal posts too.